Ubuntu crashes while trying to load its virtual machine
I have been trying to make an operating system based on ubuntu. When i download the iso file and set up the virtual machine, loading into ubuntu works fine. But when i hit the install option, it gives me an error and my whole OS freezes.
I have:

Intel pentium 4
980 MB of memory

Virtual box VM uses:

450 MB of Base Memory.

1 CPU with 100% Execution cap ( PAE/NX enabled ).

128 MB of Video Memory.

No 3D or 2D Acceleration.

Enabled usb controller.

USB 1.1 ( OHCI ) Controller Enabled.

Ubuntu Mini 18.04 "Bionic beaver" x86.


The error i get is the Meditation guru error.
If anybody wants the log, here it is.
https://www.mediafire.com/file/ef1xo41ixiky2b7/VBox.log.3/file

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! To allow readers to understand your problem, please edit your question to add the following essential information: the version of Ubuntu you are experiencing the problem with, the virtualization environment and settings you are using, and, most importantly, the actual error message you are receiving. Thanks.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.

As the Guru Meditation error message says, this is a VirtualBox problem and you should get help from the VirtualBox community. However, your log shows "VCPU0: Guru Meditation -2403 (VERR_TRPM_DONT_PANIC)" which a quick search of StackOverflow tells me is an indication for your CPU not supporting VT-x. I remember that many Pentium 4 models lacked that support and were therefore unsuitable for virtualization.

@Tilman aw mann. thats sad. i wanted to make an os for a while now and wanting to do it on this machine is impossible. ill try to look if an older version is possible such as some 4.3 version i think. anyways, thanks!
